# Get Errors printing wrong SQL statement to stdout python

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, stdout

With the following command I run a python script that prints an SQL insert statement to stdout: `xzcat ../file.txt|grep –i ‘some text’|python3.7 pythonscriptname|mysql –h host –u username –ppassword databasename`

I want to catch errors if I print a SQL statement with the wrong syntax or for example a table that does not exists. I do not want to use mysql.connector or mysqldb to insert data or catch errors, because printing a insert statement to stdout is faster.

I have to the following code:

```
try: 
     sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO "+str(wrongtabelname)+" VALUES"+values+";"                          
     print(sql)
except: (SQLError, Exception, NameError,IndexError, TypeError, ValueError,ProgrammingError, Attrib
uteError, KeyError, BrokenPipeError,IOError, OSError, ConnectionAbortedError, ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionError) as
 e:
```

This code does not catch any errors when running the code with a wrong SQL statement. Does anyone know how to catch errors?

Answer (score 0):

You pipe `xzcat` to `python` to `mysql`.

The only process in this chain that will ever see the result of the SQL query execution is the `mysql` client.

If you want the `mysql` output back into python, consider calling `mysql` from inside your python script. Use the `subprocess` module for that.

Comment: I want to receive a sigpipeerror, but I am not getting it when inserting a wrong SQL statement

Comment: You won't get SIGPIPE unless there is no mysql client available or unable to consume stdin. The pipe is presumably successful, only the mysql client process fails with nonzero exit code. Python will not be able to detect that because the python process already exited before mysql was executed. What you want needs a different architecture where the python script calls mysql as a subprocess.